# Почему ничего не появляется в терминале SSH при соединение с удаленным сервером?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sudo

[image: Чтобы я сюда не вводил ничего не происходит]

Помогите мне я полный ноль в таких вещах, но произошло это все после того как я использовал команду **sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve**

Comment: возьмите новый сервер, этому уже не помочь

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /` классика =))

Comment: Это троллинг такой? Сегодня вроде бы не первое апреля...

Comment: Ну классика же, ну. https://lurkmore.to/Rm_-rf

Answer (score 2):

Если выполнить команду:

```
sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve
```

то все данные с корневого раздела диска будут удалены!

> Иногда данная команда используется, чтобы «подшутить» над новичками в Linux. Некоторые пользователи на форумах советуют «чайникам» выполнить данную команду, чтобы решить свои проблемы. Чтобы шутка удалась, саму команду иногда маскируют, например, вставляют ее внутрь другой длинной команды, чтобы она не так выделялась.

Процесс работы `rm -rf /` примерно следующий:

- Команда выполняется от имени суперпользователя.
- Копия программы `rm` загружается в оперативную память.
- Программа `rm` начинает удаление всех файлов с корневого раздела `/`.
- Во время удаления файлов программа `rm` в какой-то момент удаляет и саму себя (исполняемый файл программы, файл `/bin/rm`). Но так как копия программы находится в оперативной памяти, то она продолжает работать, не смотря на то, что исполняемый файл уже удален.
- Когда удаление файлов завершено, программа `rm` выгружается из оперативной памяти.
- На данном этапе в памяти находятся только те программы, которые уже были там до выполнения команды `rm` (например: ядро, драйвера, окно терминала и так далее).

> Все, что вы прочитали выше, написано только в информационных целях, не
> повторяйте этого на своем компьютере!